# python if answer is correct display a well done message?

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I'm trying to set a memory word game where the program reads a text file with 10 words. The program reads the file and creates a list of 9 out of the words .pop() the last word no.10. The words are randomly shuffled and then displayed again with a 2nd list of the same words randomly shuffled with the last word .pop() and the 1st removed is replacing the word (removed / substituted) - hope that sort of explains it.

I an having an issue regarding feeding back the right response wh`enter code here`en the user guesses the correct answer (it nots) everything else appears to be working.

```
import time
from random import shuffle

file =open('Words.txt', 'r')
word_list = file.readlines()

word_list [0:9]
shuffle(word_list)
extra_word=(word_list.pop())

 print (extra_word)#substitute word for 2nd question (delete this line)
 print '...............'

 print (word_list)

print ('wait and now see the new list')
time.sleep(3)
print ('new lists')

word_list [0:9]
shuffle(word_list)
newExtra_word=(word_list.pop())

 print (newExtra_word)#replace word for 1st question (delete this line)    

 word_list.insert(9,extra_word)# replace word 

 print (word_list)
```

This code above works fine (for what i want it to do..) The section below however:

```
#ALLOW FOR 3 GUESSES
user_answer = (raw_input('can you guess the replaced word: ')).lower()
count = 0
while count <=1:
     if user_answer == newExtra_word:
          print("well done")
          break
     else:
          user_answer = (raw_input('please guess again: ')).lower()
          count+=1
else:
     print ('Fail, the answer is' +  extra_word)
```

The code does allow for three guesses, but will not accept the removed list item. Does anyone have any ideas why?

Comment: Ekhm... The downvote is not mine but I guess that because your code is very low quality (sorry to say that) and too convoluted. The question itself is legitimate. I agree that it should not be a reason for a downvote.

Comment: It is completely contrary to the spirit of Stackoverflow to down vote people simply because they're beginners or the quality of their example code is not up the standards of more experienced programmers.  I really wish there were a way to report spurious down votes to some group of people to whom authority would be delegated to act on them.

Answer (score 2):

Well, because your code above DOESN'T work the way you want it to.

```
file = open('Words.txt', 'r')
word_list = file.readlines()
# you should do file.close() here

word_list[0:9]
```

That last line doesn't actually do anything. It returns the first 10 elements in `word_list` but you never assign them to anything, so it's essentially a `NOP`. Instead do

```
word_list = word_list[0:9] # now you've removed the extras.
```

Probably better is to shuffle first so you have a truly random set of 10. Why 10? Why are we restricting the data? Oh well, okay...

```
# skipping down a good ways
word_list.insert(9, extra_word) # replace word
```

Why are we doing this? I don't really understand what this operation is supposed to do.

As for allowing three guesses:

```
count = 0
while count < 3:
    user_answer = raw_input("Can you guess the replaced word: ").lower()
    count += 1
    if user_answer == newExtra_word:
        print("well done")
        break
else:
    print("Sorry, the answer is " + extra_word)
```

Wait, did you catch that? You're checking the user input against `newExtra_word` then you're reporting the correct answer as `extra_word`. Are you sure your code logic works?

What it SOUNDS like you want to do is this:

```
with open("Words.txt") as inf:
    word_list = [next(inf).strip().lower() for _ in range(11)]
    # pull the first _11_ lines from Words.txt, because we're
    # going to pop one of them.

word_going_in = word_list.pop()
random.shuffle(word_list)

print ' '.join(word_list)

random.shuffle(word_list)
word_coming_out = word_list.pop()
# I could do word_list.pop(random.randint(0,9)) but this
# maintains your implementation

word_list.append(word_going_in)
random.shuffle(word_list)

count = 0
while count < 3:
    user_input = raw_input("Which word got replaced? ").lower()
    count += 1
    if user_input == word_coming_out:
        print "Well done"
        break
else:
    print "You lose"
```